# How can we transfer files using SFTP from Python?

Tags: python

I want to transfer files using SFTP from Python.

I tried installing the `pysftp` module, but it has dependencies like `pycrypto`, etc. Are there any alternative packages available to transfer files using SFTP from Python?

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is called creating a minimal, reproducible example (reprex), a minimal, complete and verifiable example (mcve), or a minimal, workable example (mwe). - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: you can use paramiko

Answer (score 0):

The sftp protocol works above `SSH`, so it's using `TCP` for communications.
The use of `pycrypto` is necessary as you will need to use (even if it'll be unvisible for you) many cryptographic functions.
When reading the pysftp documentation [PYSFTP](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/), you only need a dependancy to `paramiko`, so you could only try to install it.